# JSON parse error: Unrecognized field MongoDB Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-java

I am trying to save the following Java object as a document in MongoDB, here are my classes:

```
public class GenericIpConfig {
    String connection_type;
    String port;
    String port_ingenico;
    String ip;
    String ip_ingenico;
    String id_ingenico;
    boolean active_ingenico;
    long lastPushTime;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "generic_device_config")
public class GenericDeviceConfig {
    @Id
    String _id;

    String storeCode;
    String companyCode;

    long updated;
    boolean enabled;

    ArrayList<SerialPort> serialPorts;
    String companyId;

    GenericIpConfig ipConfig;
}
```

And this is the request I am sending with POSTMAN:

```
{
    "updated":0,
    "enabled":true,
    "serialPorts":[],
    "companyId":"600",
    "companyCode":"0",
    "storeCode":"0",
    "ipConfig": {
        "connection_type":"ETHERNET",
        "port": "23",
        "port_ingenico": "",
        "ip": "192.168.10.55",
        "ip_ingenico": "",
        "id_ingenico": "",
        "active_ingenico": false,
        "lastPushTime": 0
    }
}
```

For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

```
JSON parse error: Unrecognized field \"connection_type\" (class it.igesa.monitoringsystem.model.mongo.device.config.GenericIpConfig), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field \"connection_type\" (class it.igesa.monitoringsystem.model.mongo.device.config.GenericIpConfig), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ]
```

I feel like my code is missing something, since this is the first time I am working with SpringBoot/MongoDB;

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Jackson can't recognise setter methods for fields, because they don't follow java naming conventions. Try fixing the unrecognised fields with this annotation - `@JsonProperty("property_name_here")`, by putting it on the setters.

You are also mixing them, some of your fields are named `something_something`, while others are `somethingSomething`, which is the standard java way. It's a good idea to pick one and stick to it for the project.

You should also read up on serialization with jackson [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/), [annotation examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I keep getting the same error :/

Comment: @joe1531 Ok, can you update your question to show your  complete classes - fields, getters, setters, constructors, and your exact attempt at fixing the error. I think more people should be able to give ideas like this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. Defining setters and getters annotations for the nested class solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra getter method in a class that I was reusing.
It worked fine when I removed the extra getter.
I hope you find this useful too.
Thanks a lot.